# How to calculate number of combinations and integrate in a function?

Tags: r, combinations

When I try to calculate combinations in R using the Combinat package and the combn command it gives me all possible combinations. But i want to integrate all combinations in a function (reqn) and then print all. What should I do?

```
df1 <- c(1234,1333,1332,1333,15,1234,15, 162, 1234)
num1<- c(1,2,3,1,4,2,2, 2,3)
data.frame(df1,num1)
reqn<-c(1,3)
names(Filter(identity, 
               apply(table(df1, factor(num1, levels=reqn))>0, 1, all)))
install.packages("combinat")
require(combinat)
combn(3, 2)
```

Comment: What does " But i want to integrate all combinations in a function (reqn) and then print all." mean?

Comment: for example one combination is (1,2) and second (1,3). Now the program should give me for both combination the result which df1 has (1,2) and which has (1,3). 
I have a big data, its only an example of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `apply`? It's very likely that I misunderstood your question, but here's the solution to the question I believe you may be asking.

```
apply(combn(3, 2), 2, function(reqn, df){
  names(Filter(identity,
               apply(table(df1, factor(num1, levels=reqn))>0, 1, all)))
  }, df=df1)
```

Or for the same result

```
combn(3, 2, function(reqn, df){
  names(Filter(identity,
               apply(table(df1, factor(num1, levels=reqn))>0, 1, all)))
  }, df=df1, simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! that's what I've been looking for

Comment: +1 for passing a function to `combn`.

Comment: @shadow 
Now I have another Problem:

        result <-combn(4, 2, function(reqn, df){
        names(Filter(identity,
        apply(table(df1, factor(num1, levels=reqn))>0, 1, all)))
        }, df=df1, simplify=FALSE)
        View(result)

Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 0

Comment: And what is the problem? The `result` is a `list` and some of the combinations return no answer. `View` coerces `result` to a `data.frame`, which is not possible if some of the entries have length 0. You should not use `View`, or if you are only interested in the results of positive length, you could use `View(res[sapply(res, length)>0])`.